# Convert code C# to VB - Function references

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have some C# code I'm trying to convert to VB.NET. There are some external dependencies I'm referencing in each project. The C# line is

```
TWriteFileCommand writeFile = (TWriteFileCommand)CommunicationLink.CreateCommand(TOPKernel.TCommand.CommandType.WriteFile);
```

I don't really understand what the TWriteFileCommand in parathesis after the equal sign is for in that statement. When I try to do it in VB.NET, I keep getting errors because I can't get a reference to the CreateCommand function. The closest I've gotten is this:

```
Dim MyAppBase As OPSupport.App.AppBase
Dim writeFile As TWriteFileCommand
writeFile = MyAppBase.CommunicationLink.CreateCommand(TOPKernel.TCommand.CommandType.WriteFile)
```

However, I have a green underline after the equal sign @ MyAppBase that flags an error "Variable MyAppBase is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

What am I missing? Why in the C# code is the instance fine and what do I need to get the equivalent instance in VB.NET? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct equivalent is:

```
Dim writeFile As TWriteFileCommand 
writeFile = DirectCast(CommunicationLink.CreateCommand(TOPKernel.TCommand.CommandType.WriteFile), TWriteFileCommand)
```

Comment: Others answered something similar, but this was the one I read first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That is a cast; if `CreateCommand` returns `object`, `CommandBase`, or anything like that - it does the type-check to `TWriteFileCommand`.

If you have compiling C# code - can you use reflector to do the translation? This shows you C# and equivalent VB at a flip of a drop-down.

I'm not sure what the `MyAppBase` is doing; that didn't exist in the C# - why did you add it to the VB?

**edit** I don't "do" VB, but I looked it up in reflector; `(Foo)bar` becomes `DirectCast(bar, Foo)`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `CreateCommand` is a static method in the `CommunicationLink` type. Either that, or there's a property called `CommunicationLink`, and the type of that has a `CreateCommand` method.

The bit in brackets after the = is a cast. Use `CType` or `DirectCast` to do this in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The `()` are one of C#'s ways of casting from one type to another.  The VB equivalent is `CType()`.

Comment: He will need to cast, but the current error is because his MyAppBase object is null, and not static/shared.

Comment: Good point - it did also seem like he was confused as to how to do a cast with VB syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the CommunicationLink variable decalred *and instantiated* in the C# code?  You need to make sure the VB code uses the same source for that object.

Answer (score 0):

I can' really see where did `Dim MyAppBase As OPSupport.App.AppBase` came from.

As far as `(TWriteFileCommand)` is concerned, this is a type cast. `DirectCast` has (almost?) the same functionality.

Comment: C# () cast is somewhere in between CType() and DirectCast, since it will honor implicit/explicit conversions where DirectCast will not, but won't do as much extra work as the CType() operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you dont assign a variable value to MyAppBase :-)

```
Dim MyAppBase As OPSupport.App.AppBase = new OPSupport.App.AppBase()
Dim writeFile As TWriteFileCommand
writeFile = MyAppBase.CommunicationLink.CreateCommand(TOPKernel.TCommand.CommandType.WriteFile)
```

?

Comment: I had tried declaring it as new before but it gives me an error "'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'"